# Error en valor de ID

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, autoincremento

Al hacer un registro en la BD el id lo autoincrementa mal,
no sigue la misma secuencia del anterior ID que se
encuentra en la BD

```
 <script lang="ts" setup>
    import {Ref, ref, onMounted} from "vue"
    import axios from "axios";
    import { DropdownPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";
    let nombre = ref("")
    let dato = ref()
    const enviar=()=>{ let config = { headers: {
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data', } }
        let formData=new FormData()
        formData.append("name",nombre.value)
        axios.post('http://localhost:8888/insertar/', formData, config)
        .then((response)=> {
            let t = response.data
            if(t.status=="OK"){
                //mostrar aviso 
                console.log(t.message+": "+t.data)}
            dameDatos()})
            .catch((error)=> {
                console.log(error);
            });  }
```

Comment: que quiere decir que no sigue la misma secuencia? se saltea numeros?

Comment: Es normal que los campos autoincrementales de las bases de datos no sean secuencias perfectas de números en una tabla, por diversas razones. Lo que garantizan los autoincrementales es que no se va a repetir 2 veces el mismo número, y que el siguiente siempre será mayor que el anterior. Esto no quiere decir que el motor no genere números consecutivos, pero formar un agujero es tan sencillo como iniciar una sesión, hacer un insert y luego hacer rollback de la transacción. Hay otras maneras. ¿Por qué esperas tú que sea un consecutivo perfecto? ¿Siempre tienes agujeros?